# Can you call an async function in a DetailsList?

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx

I have an async function in a SPFx web part which gets data from a SPO list.

```
    public async getTabData(theList = "ListOfLinks") {

      console.log('getTabData');

      let web = Web(this.props.webURL);
web.lists.getByTitle("ListOfLinks").items.select(...colsToSelect).get();
      const items: any[] = await web.lists.getByTitle(theList).items.get();
      console.log('items:' + items);
```

Is it possible to call this function from a DetailsList?

I try to do this

```
<DetailsList          
                  items={this.getTabData(item.ListToShow)}
```

but it says ...

```
Type 'Promise<any[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.ts(2740)
DetailsList.types.d.ts(60, 5): The expected type comes from property 'items' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IDetailsListProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'
(JSX attribute) IDetailsListProps.items: any[]
```

Thanks
P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `<DetailsList />` accepts `items` prop as an **array**, while `getTabData()` returns a **promise**.

What I would do is to create a state for the items, call `getTabData()` function after the component renders in `componentDidMount()`, and update `items` inside `getTabData()` after the asyncronous work is finished.

Once `items` is updated, the component will re-render with new data.

```js
class YourComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.items = [];
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getTabData(item.ListToShow);
  }

  public async getTabData(theList = "ListOfLinks") {
    let web = Web(this.props.webURL);
    web.lists
      .getByTitle("ListOfLinks")
      .items.select(...colsToSelect)
      .get();
    const items: any[] = await web.lists.getByTitle(theList).items.get();
    console.log("items:" + items);

    this.setState({ items });
  }

  render() {}
}
```

Comment: Hi Moaaz thanks for the help. DEtailsList is from fluentui https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui/#/controls/web/detailslist

Comment: If I try to put useEffect into my render method I get this error ... Cannot find name 'useEffect'.

Comment: Oh, I should've known that you used class component, not function. `useEffect` is for functional component. In your case, use `componentDidMount()`. Will update my answer.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks ComponentDidMount only seems to load on the first load of the page. When I click on PivotItems it doesn't seem to get called again?

Comment: Yes, `ComponentDidMount` only runs once after the component is _mounted_ (created). If you want to run `getTabData()` function again in response to a button click, you can simply add it to `onClick` prop of that button. e.g. `<Button onClick={this.getTabData} />`

Comment: You can call the function wherever you want, and it will update `this.state.items`. You just can't use it directly in `items` prop of  `<DetailsList />` component because it returns a promise, not an array.